# How do we lose control of an omen if it can't be dropped, traded, or stolen?

Tags: betrayal-at-baldurs-gate

I was playing a game of B@BG last week and a question came up with the meenlock omen card. It says that it 'cannot be dropped, traded or stolen,' but also says 'if you **lose control of this omen** lose two speed'. How do you lose control of an omen? We presumed that to lose control of an item, it must be taken from you, but the meenlock can't be stolen. What other ways can you lose control of an omen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specific haunts scenarios can cause you to lose them. Especially haunts that directly involve them (haunts that are triggered by them being found). Some haunts may, for example, immediately in the setup cause the traitor to take possession of the omen. Others will involve players fighting over the omen, and include specific rules for how you can take or lose the omen.